App freezes when completing StoreKit purchase and using .fullScreenCover modifier in SwiftUI
My SwiftUI app freezes when completing a purchase in StoreKit if I have .fullScreenCover modifier applied anywhere in the View hierarchy.
It doesn't matter where I put the .fullScreenCover modifier in the view hierarchy. Even if I place it somewhere else in the hierarchy and don't trigger it, the app will still freeze on completed purchase. As soon as I remove .fullScreenCover modifier everything works great.
Anyone else had this issue? Is this a known issue? Is there a fix for this?
struct ShopView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    @State var isFullScreenCoverPresented: Bool = false
    @State var purchasedTip: Tip? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(store.products.sorted(by: { $0.price < $1.price })) { product in
                    ProductView(product) {
                        Image("productImage")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onInAppPurchaseCompletion { product, result in
            if case .success(.success(.verified(let transaction))) = result {
                await store.process(transaction)
                // make sure there's a Tip corresponding to the purchased product
                if let tip = Tip(rawValue: product.id) {
                    purchasedTip = tip
                }
                // show thank you note in full screen cover
                isFullScreenCoverPresented = true
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullScreenCoverPresented) {
            if let tip = purchasedTip {
                ThankYouNote(tip: tip)
            }
        }
    }
}


When it freezes, ThankYouNote is displayed on the full-screen cover as expected?

What's the implementation of the onInAppPurchaseCompletion method?

@Toru The app may freeze on ThankYouNote, or right after successful purchase alert before the note even appears. Also, the app will freeze even if I don't trigger full-screen cover, and just have the fullScreenCover modifier applied anywhere in the hierarchy

@VadimBelyaev Could you please elaborate what you mean?
I'll try answer your question anyway. onInAppPurchaseCompletion is a modifier supplied by StoreKit and SwiftUI. As far as I know. the StoreKit calls it when any ProductView in the view hierarchy completes purchase. Here's documentation.
Does this answer your question?
